# How do I restart a NuoDB database?

Tags: database, distributed, nuodb

How do I start the Community edition of NuoDB (on any of the supported systems: Linux, Windows, MacOS, EC2, Ubuntu)
http://dev.nuodb.com/download-nuodb/request/download

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on whether or not you are running the database as Managed or UnManaged.

**Managed Database**
Restarting a managed database is done via the Automation console.
1. Browse to Databases
2. Select the "start" button for the database that you wish start.

**Unmanaged Database**
Restarting an unmanaged database requires a little more effort than a Managed database as you will have to create a capture file and execute command through the NuoDB Manager CLI.

*using nuodbmgr*

1.) Create a capture file of the database

```
nuodb [domain] > capture database My_Database dbFile My_Database.cap
```

2.) Shutdown the database

```
nuodb [domain] > shutdown database My_Database
```

3.) Restart the database

```
nuodb [domain] > restart database dbFile My_Database.cap
```